# How to search with GNU find for several file types at a time?

Tags: find

How is it possible to use the GNU find command to match several file types at a time (one search command)?

The man page says:

```
-type c
    File is of type c:
    b      block (buffered) special
    c      character (unbuffered) special
    d      directory
    p      named pipe (FIFO)
    f      regular file
    l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -follow
           option  is in  effect,  unless  the  symbolic link is broken.  If
           you want to search for symbolic links when -L is in effect, use
           -xtype.
    s      socket
    D      door (Solaris)
```

and I want to search for files (`f`) and symbolic links (`l`) and pipe it to another process. How can I search for both at the same time?

I have tried

```
find -type fl | …
find -type f -type l | …
find -xtype f -type l | …
```

I know a workaround would be to use a subshell

```
(find -type f; find -type l) | …
```

but I just want to know **if** it is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can group and use logical operators with find, but you have to escape the parens so you could look for all files and links like

```
find \( -type f -o -type l \) <other filters>
```

so if you wanted all files and links whose name starts with t you could do

```
find \( -type f -o -type l \) -name 't*'
```

You only need the parens if you want to group things and combine with other opeators, so if you have no other search criteria you can omit them

Comment: The additional explanation with the parenthesis gave you the win, because that would have been my next problem. Thanks for reading my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find -type f -o -type l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the predicates using `-a` (for `and`) or `-o` (for `or`).  So, you can type

```
find /path -type f -o -type l
```